# Vagrant Not Starting Up. User that created VM doesn't match current user

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualenv

I was trying to start up my vagrant machine, so I navigated to the folder where my vagrantfile is, and used:

vagrant up && vagrant ssh

but I got the following error message:

> The VirtualBox VM was created with a user that doesn't match the
>   current user running Vagrant. VirtualBox requires that the same user
>   be used to manage the VM that was created. Please re-run Vagrant with
>   that user. This is not a Vagrant issue.
>
> The UID used to create the VM was: 0 Your UID is: 501

I also tried with sudo, but that didn't work either.

Do I need to switch UID's? And how would I do this?

Answer (score 268, accepted):

I ran into the same problem today.
I edited my **UID** by opening the file `.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/creator_uid` and changing the **501** to a **0**.

After I saved the file, the command vagrant up worked like a champ.

NB: the `.vagrant` folder is in the same directory as your Vagrantfile, where you ran `vagrant up`

Comment: I found myself in the same situation, I had tar up a tarball from an ubuntu machine. So simply removing the `rm -rf .vagrant` dir that got created in ubuntu also resolved the issue.

Comment: // , Wow, thanks, @Fred! Stackoverflow serves us at its best with this kind of precise, difficult to find solution from someone who has had to deal with it before. Where will I usually find the `.vagrant` folder on Unix based machines?

Comment: Not sure, @Nathan.  Can you run a locate command for the creator_uid file?  Try "locate creator_uid" at the command line to find the path to the file to edit.

Comment: // , That worked. I use my CEntOS box from `~/vagrant/centos/`. It looks like the `creator_uid` file was at `~/vagrant/centos/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/creator_uid`. This seems to mean that the `.vagrant` in this answer usually has the same directory as the `Vagrantfile` for the problem machine.

Comment: In my case, the creator_uid contained "90210", but my UID is 502.  Rather than change the UID in the file to 0 as this solution suggested, I changed it to 502.  Worked well.

Comment: Thanks! I created a VM on my Mac, and then had my machine cloned to a new Mac. Everything about the system (other than the improved hardware) behaved the same, as far as I can tell, until I ran into this. Apparently my UID changed from 510 to 502.

Comment: @NathanBasanese `.vagrant` folder is at the same location you ran `vagrant up`

Comment: Why can't I find the "creator_uid" file in the given directory?

Comment: Remove simply `.vagrant` at the root of your Vagrantfile

Comment: I worked I had same issue just made change in creatoruid file

Comment: It worked, although my vagrant file was at `.vagrant/machines/dev/virtualbox/creator_uid`

Answer (score 37):

Ran into this problem in a slightly different situation. The issue was that ".vagrant" was checked into the git repo, and the committer was running under a different UID than I was.

Solution: add .vagrant to .gitignore.

Comment: This was the issue I faced; however, simply adding `.vagrant` to `.gitignore` will *not* solve the issue - YMMV, but `git rm -rf .vagrant` should be run too.

Comment: @marco: You're absolutely right. if ".vagrant" was added to the repo, adding it to .gitignore afterwards is too late :)

Answer (score 8):

I tried changing the id in .vagrant\machines\default\virtualbox\creator_uid and that did not work for me but deleting the file, creator_uid did the trick.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same issue, but in my case it was because I had ran `vagrant up` under `sudo`, and when I came back to it later I'd forgotten.

Silly mistake, but I'm sure it's not the first time it's happened someone :)

Comment: Same issue here, forgot to run under `sudo`. But the error message is not very indicative of that unfortunately.

Comment: Same here. Used `sudo vagrant up` but then used `vagrant ssh` which threw the different user error. Forgot to use `sudo vagrnt ssh` which worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

just change user ID here
.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/creator_uid

Answer (score 2):

It's possible you ran the command: `sudo vagrant up`

This would mean as your regular user you are unable to see or even delete the `/.vagrant` folder and files.

If so, simply run: `sudo vagrant destroy -f`

Then you should be able to run (as your normal user account): `vagrant up`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [VirtualBox User Manual](http://en.helpdoc-online.com/virtualbox_4.1.2/source/ch06s05.html):

> As a security measure, the Linux implementation of internal networking
>   only allows VMs running under the same user ID to establish an
>   internal network.

In other words, you have to switch to root (`UID 0`) to run it.

Comment: Shouldn't run as sudo, just delete your .vagrant directory and run as your user

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands:

```
bash
sudo vagrant up
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. I deleted in .vagrant directory inside the directory where Vagrantfile was present. Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after I got a new computer. Instead of of copying all files from my old computer, I had to check out the vagrant projects *again* from the git repository. After that, `vagrant up` worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to Fred's https://stackoverflow.com/a/32256848/2065804 answer.

Make sure you changed the correct VM's machine. For example, my VM name is NOT default but rather called homestead-7.

So the path to **the correct one** is:

```
.vagrant/machines/homestead-7/virtualbox/creator_uid
```

and not:

```
.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/creator_uid
```

This error happened to me when I changed my Mac to another Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the content of .vagrant hidden dir in the current working dir and re-run vagrant up command.
Error, because of copy / backup of Vagranfile /s from one system to another system. user id's mismath to the Vagrant to bring up the environment.. 
hope it helps cheers..!! :))
if u don't wish to delete that folder u can update uid of current user in file in the hidden dir of current working dir, i.e  .vagrant/machines/jenkins/virtualbox$ vim creator_uid

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same situation, but I have a [multi-machine](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/multi-machine/) Vagrantfile.

To replace the old uid (1001) by the new one (1000) I've used the following command:

```
for i in $(find . -type f -iname "creator_uid" ) ; do echo 1000 > $i ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem I had forgotten to place `sudo` before `vagrant up`, you just have to execute `sudo vagrant up` in the folder of your vagrant file.

Answer (score 0):

I have Multi-Machine vagrant file. I have checked the `creator_uid` and it is `0` but still unable to load. So I have deleted `creator_uid` file for all the Multi-Machine and it worked. Path should be `.vagrant\machines\<machine_name>\virtualbox`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue but it's because I cloned an exercise file from a GitHub repo. I found the issue being the .vagrant file included in the repository.

What worked for me is deleting the .vagrant directory and rerun `vagrant up`

Answer (score -2):

rm -rf .vagrant/machines/default/creator_uid

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).