# VirtualBox VM was created with a user that doesn't match the current user running Vagrant

Tags: windows, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrant-windows

[image: Error while running vagrant]

I'm new in Windows. I use Windows 10. While I run vagrant on my machine, there are some issues with UID. Please look at the picture for more information.

While I run `vagrant up`, I get some warning :

```
The VirtualBox VM was created with a user that doesn't match the
current user running Vagrant. VirtualBox requires that the same user
be used to manage the VM that as created. Please re-run Vagrant with
that user. This is not a Vagrant issue.

The UID used to create the VM was: 1000
Your UID is: 0
```

Comment: I found [similar problem in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644222/vagrant-not-starting-up-user-that-created-vm-doesnt-match-current-user/32977467) but I didn't know how to apply that case in my Windows 10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vagrant Not Starting Up. User that created VM doesn't match current user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644222/vagrant-not-starting-up-user-that-created-vm-doesnt-match-current-user)

Answer (score 8):

Looks like you are logged in as sudo, hence the UID is different. Log-out of sudo and try vagrant up as normal user.

If the above doesn't work then update the below file

> vi .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/creator_uid

to add 0 in it

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Find this path and change to 0.

> .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/creator_uid

Answer (score 3):

Remove .vagrant dir in the current working dir and re-run vagrant up command.
Error, because of copy / backup of Vagranfile /s from one system to another system. user id's mismath to the Vagrant to bring up the environment.. 
hope it helps cheers..!! :))

Answer (score 2):

In the Windows folder. Vagrant is in the same folder as the Vagrantfile.
As default won't be available, so you may have to edit in every vm but the path is the same: `vagrant/machines/(name of the vm)/virtualbox/creator_uid`

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me (on subsequent runs) when I used `vagrant up` with elevated privileges for the first time (administrator).